# Use graphviz with python3

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz, decision-tree

I try to draw a decision tree using the graphviz module, and it works fine with python2. Is there a way to use this module with python3?
Is there any other module that supports drawing decision trees in python3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module to draw a decision tree with python3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604310/module-to-draw-a-decision-tree-with-python3)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install graphviz for python3? It works fine for me:

```
andi@sunnyside:~$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import graphviz
>>>
```

I am using debian though and there is no debian package for graphviz itself, you have to install it with pip3.