# Trouble installing graphviz for python3 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz, decision-tree

I want to draw a decision tree with python3. Yet I can only find modules for python2: `graphviz`, `ete3`
Did I miss something? Can I use them with python3? Do you know any other possibilities?

I use Ubuntu 14.04.

**Edit:**

I tried the command `sudo python3 -m pip install graphviz`, but it still can't find the module.

Comment: I don't know if there is a module for this specifically, but any xml module like ElementTree might do an implementation quite well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Graphviz's PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz), it is available for Python 3.

On Ubuntu make sure you have graphviz with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pygraphviz
```

Perhaps Python3 can't find your installed graphviz? Did you install it with, e.g.

```
python3 -m pip install graphviz
```

On Ubuntu you might try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install graphviz
```

You haven't told us what your system is, which may affect the advice you are given.

If you're on Windows, I usually recommend installing Anaconda and using its package manager (it comes with almost all the things, but not graphviz so you'd have to use its package manager to install, but I'd expect it to work out of the gate once you did install it).

If you're on Mac or Linux, try installing with the command I gave above (or whatever your Python 3 executable uses.)

Comment: if I run the code with `python2` it works fine, but if I run it using `python3` it tells me `graphviz` is missing. I installed it using `pip`

Comment: @Jonas updated my answer. See if you can follow my instructions and provide more information on your question  about your system, or comment here if my answer worked for you.

Comment: I use ubuntu 14.04, I tried your command to install graphviz, please see me edit.

Comment: Thank you, now it is working! I think I understand the concept behind python2/3 not a little bit better